# AJAX search box altering the contents of a list

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I just couldn't figure out how to utilise an AJAX powered search box to alter the contents of a list.

So basically, the dream is to have the user entering a query in the box and the list below will be altered so that it contains the entries whose title matches the query.

The screenshot below might help;

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What hasn't worked?  How about showing us the code you've written so far to begin solving the problem?  Without a starting point, it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: @Charles Well, to be honest I am looking for a starting point. I can make use of the query to filter the entries using database. However, I can't make the connection that will allow me to re-list entries in the list. It will probably be possible by using DOM alongside jQuery but the question is how?

Comment: How can there be a starting point if you don't start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just looking for a starting point, follow these simple steps to make the sense out of it.

1. You need to write a code-block( preferably a function ) in php that will take, what user types, as input and query for items to be listed from the database based on that input.
2. Next you need to loop through your output retrieved from the query and modify it's structure if you need to OR prepare the HTML for it in php and send it as a response to your browser.
3. Now do an ajax call(see this - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to that php code-block, may be using jQuery on the event **keypress** (see this - http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).
4. Now replace the old list with the newly received data.

Thats just about an idea what should be your workflow. Pasting code for all of these will make the answer really long. So just a work-flow.

PHP(ajaxcall.php):

```
<?php 

 //The following code block will be executed on the ajax call.


//get the user input from post
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

//do the query based on that.
//YOUR SQL HERE

//parse the retrieved result and loop through it.

//echo out the output.

die();
```

JS:

```
$('.somefield').keypress(function(){
    //get the current value of some field and set this as the data to be sent.
    //do your ajax call.
    //on success( after successfully getting the data ), replace the content of
    //the list with the new data.
});
```

Comment: You may wanna accept the answer of comment if you have problems in understanding my answer.